# Xamarin, Android: How to build an if clause for a certain parameter?

Tags: if-statement, xamarin

this might seem a little easy but I hope you guys can answer me anyway :)

So, I have this line of code:

```
    mLocationManager.SetTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider, true);
```

Later in my code this appears:

```
        mLocationManager.RemoveTestProvider(LocationManager.GpsProvider);
```

My app will crash, when the TestProvider was NOT enabled and I try to remove it. So I want to build an if clause that would look somehow like this:

if (TestProviderIsEnabled = True) 
{xxx}

As you can see, this would need to check for the second parameter (the true), and see if it is true or false. Yet I can't seem to put up the correct if clause... Can anybody help me with this? :)

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mLocationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPpsProvider))
{
XXX
}
```

I hope it could help

Comment: hi thanks! unfortunately, for some reason my program will always go into this if statement, no matter if i already set up a fake provider or if i didnt...

Comment: ah i see, this didnt help because all this does is checked whether a provider is enabled at all. but i need to check if a fake provider is already enabled !

Answer (score 0):

You seem to miss an additional = in the condition.
`if (X = True)`
Is most likely setting X to true and then verifying that X is true. You probably wanted to write
`if (X == True)`

On the other hand that is actually one extra comparison operation because first it checks that if X equals to True and then checks if the result is true.
Why not simply write
`if (X)`?
It translates to fewer CPU instructions, beside eliminating the possibility of the silly bug above and improving code readability.